# Clicking reCAPTCHA checkbox causes crash in IE11

Tags: bug, captcha, internet-explorer

I have IE11 opened, searched a few times on StackOverflow, and was navigated to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha?s=d98dd1d5-da64-45dd-81bc-c886f7a1713b) site.

[image: reCAPTCHA]

Clicking on "I'm not a robot" causes IE11 to prompt me with "IE has stopped working" and gives me the options of checking for solution and closing, closing the program, or debugging.  Clicking "Close the program," closes the tab (I had multiple open), reopens another one and brings me back to the same site listed above.  Showing more details, I see:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: IEXPLORE.EXE
  Application Version:  11.0.9600.17840
  Application Timestamp:    555fe1bb
  Fault Module Name:    msjava.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.0.2752.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   35747274
  Exception Offset: 000c5a6c
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   00000008
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: f7f6
  Additional Information 2: f7f6b0a3d15d9984ffbe5dd78218ca69
  Additional Information 3: b686
  Additional Information 4: b68610127775fcc81dbb8d7bcb383858

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Because there is a reference to `msjava.dll` I must say that I do know that my IT department tries to restrict Java components, via Java Deployment Set,  from running in IE.  I have figured out some workarounds thanks to having Admin rights, however when a Java app tries to run, I'm usually prompted with a "Allow" window.  In both Chrome and IE, I am not prompted with said window.

Clicking the "I'm not a robot" checkbox in Google Chrome, I see the green check mark symbol show in animated fashion and I can continue to use the site.  Is this SE or is it IE at fault?

Comment: I expect this to be an issue with [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/), not with SE. Maybe your specific use-case scenario requires a fallback but that would be about it.

Comment: Is not using IE11 an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question but as it was never answered:
Your details show that the cause of the crash is an access violation:

```
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   00000008

#define STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION          ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000005L)    // winnt
```

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

> Exception Data contains details of the kind of access violation and
>   MSDN documents type 8: The first element of the array contains a
>   read-write flag that indicates the type of operation that caused the
>   access violation. If this value is zero, the thread attempted to read
>   the inaccessible data. If this value is 1, the thread attempted to
>   write to an inaccessible address. If this value is 8, the thread
>   causes a user-mode data execution prevention (DEP) violation.

So your issue is a DEP violation which could be mitigated by changing msjava.dll with a more recent, Oracle, version of Java or by disabling DEP in Internet Explorer.